# MagicalRecord not always save changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've `UICollectionView` that populates from array which get data from CoreData with MagicalRecord. I also have button "delete" which must delete all selected cells with its objects. The problem is that my method properly delete cells and objects inside an array but not in CoreData.

**Here is a part of my method:**

```
  NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
__block int counter = 0;
[itemPaths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *itemPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ( [selectedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)itemPath.row]]  )
        {
        [indexSet addIndex:itemPath.item];
           Content *obj = self.testAssets[itemPath.item];
            NSLog(@"deleting asset # %d it is %@ in %lu",(int)idx,obj,(unsigned long)itemPaths.count);
            [nsmContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                [obj MR_deleteEntity];
                if(success){
                    counter++;
                    NSLog(@"Entity deleted!");
                } else{
                    NSLog(@"Entity NOT deleted");
                }
            }];
}];
```

Here is what I see after method ends in log window:

```
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7fb6fbc3db40) Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 3 inserted objects
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7fb6fbc3d040): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) → Save Parents? 1
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) → Save Synchronously? 0
 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 3 inserted objects
 __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x7fb6fbc3d040) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7fb6fbc3d040): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
 [NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
 [NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fb6fbc3d040) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
 Entity deleted!
 Entity NOT deleted 
 Entity NOT deleted
```

Guess I do something wrong, but can't imagine what exactly.

Comment: I know this is an inappropriate comment but why use MR? A true understanding and implementation of Core Data is so much more powerful!

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting after saving!

`MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion` saves and then runs the completion block.

Comment: does it mean that I separately must delete objects first and save context then?

Comment: you can delete all objects in your enumerate loop and once that is completed, call save which will persist any changes to the persistent store.